# z-index not working for absolute positioning for both elements

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, z-index

I have a am creating a drop down menu. SO i want the drop down meanu to have less z-index then the menu button. Both are absolute position. The code for menu buttong is as follows:

```
.menuBut
{
      /*background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7EA3D5 0%, #5C89C7 50%, #3966B0 51%, #3764AF 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7EA3D5 0%, #5C89C7 50%, #3966B0 51%, #3764AF 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7EA3D5 0%, #5C89C7 50%, #3966B0 51%, #3764AF 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #7EA3D5 0%, #5C89C7 50%, #3966B0 51%, #3764AF 100%);*/
  background-color:rgb(255,253,202);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 2px -2px 2px 1px rgb(85,85,85);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 2px -2px 2px 1px rgb(85,85,85);
    box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 2px 1px rgb(85,85,85);
    width: 28%;
    height: 48px;
    float:left;
    border:0px solid rgb(121,0,0);
    font-size:3em;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(46,49,146);
    border:1px solid rgb(85,85,85);
    z-index:300;

}

<div id = "servicesBut" style = "z-index:300;position:absolute;top:72%;left:36%;" class = "menuBut roundEdge" >Services</div>
```

The javascript code which creates the drop down on mouse enter is as below:

```
var services = ["IT Services", "HR Services", "Marketing"];
function dropCourses()
{
    //alert("drop");
    if(menuNum == 2)
    {
        var divIndWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        divIndWrapper.setAttribute("class","indimenuWrapper roundEdge19 boxShadowMenuBut");
        divIndWrapper.setAttribute("style","display:none;position:absolute;top:100%;width:100%;background:rgb(200,100,0);");

        var arry = cours;
        var inrEle = "<ul style='list-style:none;width:100%;' align = 'left' class = 'indimenu'  >";            

        for(var i = 0; i< arry.length; i++)
        {
            //inrEle+="<li style='display:block;' ><p>sadfsdf</p></li>";
            inrEle+="<li style='display:block;width:100%;opacity:1;'><input  class = 'courseSub1' style='left:0;position:absolute;width:100%;border-top:1px solid rgb(200,0,0);background:rgb(200,100,0);color:white;' type='button' value='"+arry[i]+"' onclick='courseMenuClicked(this)'/></li><br />";

        }       
        inrEle+="</ul>";
        divIndWrapper.innerHTML = inrEle;   
        //alert("mouseEnterDrop"+inrEle);
        //alert("curdropele"+curdropEle.innerHTML);
        curdropEle = document.getElementById("menu2");
        curdropEle.appendChild(divIndWrapper);  
        curCreatedEle = divIndWrapper;
        divIndWrapper.style.display = "block";  
    }
    else if(menuNum == 5)
    {       
        //alert("menu5");
        var divIndWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        divIndWrapper.setAttribute("class","indimenuWrapper roundEdge19");
        divIndWrapper.setAttribute("style","border:1px solid rgb(85,85,85);border-top:none;overflow:hidden;z-index:-1;display:none;position:absolute;left:-1px;top:80%;width:100%;background:rgb(255,248,153);");

        var arry = services;
        var inrEle = "<ul style='z-index:-1;list-style:none;width:100%;' align = 'left' class = 'indimenu'  >";         
        //alert("menu5a");
        for(var i = 0; i< arry.length; i++)
        {
            //alert("menu5"+i);
            //inrEle+="<li style='display:block;' ><p>sadfsdf</p></li>";
            inrEle+="<li style='z-index:-1;display:block;width:100%;opacity:1;'><input  class = 'courseSub1' style='z-index:250;left:0;position:absolute;width:100%;border-top:1px solid rgb(200,0,0);background:rgb(255,248,153);color:rgb(46,49,146);font-size:2em;' type='button' value='"+arry[i]+"' onclick='galleryMenuClicked(this)'/><br /><br /></li>";

        }       
        inrEle+="</ul>";
        divIndWrapper.innerHTML = inrEle;   
        //alert("mouseEnterDrop"+inrEle);
        //alert("curdropele"+curdropEle.innerHTML);
        //alert("menu5b");
        curdropEle = document.getElementById("servicesBut");
        curdropEle.appendChild(divIndWrapper);  
        //alert("menu5c");
        curCreatedEle = divIndWrapper;
        divIndWrapper.style.display = "block";  
    }
}
```

No matter what z-index i provide, the drop down div is still over the menu button. i want the menu button to be over the drop down. I know this is not true but cud it be because the drop down is a child element of menu button?

P.S. The drop down part come under menuNum = 5!!!

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle example, so we can look into it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YwXdE/

Pfa the jsfiddle link. However i dont know y but drop down is not working in JSFiddle